# How to bring up a list of live wallpapers

Tags: android

I am in the process programming my own active wallpaper and it is nearly ready. Almost by accident I discovered that within a single apk you can have a wallpaper service and an ordinary app at the same time. I noticed that the ordinary app could be arranged so that when it is run it immediately brings up a list of live wallpapers and you can have a toast message saying something like "Click on my super wallpaper to open it". To see an example try the "ocean" wallpaper on Google Play.

My question now is how do I programatically bring up a list of live wallpapers like ocean does.

Comment: has my answer solved your problem ?

Comment: Yes problem solved thanks. I can't tick for another 4 mins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can get list

```
 Intent lv = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
    //Toast
    startActivity(lv);
```